# How I can click on div(drop-down) using page-object gem with selenium (ruby-on-rails and cucumber)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, page-object-gem

I try to push on this `div`, but nothing happens:

```
<div class="uk-button-dropdown uk-width-small-1-10 uk-width-medium-1-5 uk-button uk-button-primary" data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click'}" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <span>Add Item</span>
```

My page object is defined with:

```
div(:add_item, :css => ".uk-button.uk-button-dropdown.uk-width-small-1-10")

def create_item
  sleep(2)
  add_item_element.click
  sleep(2)
end
```

If I move the mouse on the `div` during the scenario run, it works.

Comment: .uk-button-dropdown.uk-width-small-1-10.uk-width-medium-1-5.uk-button.uk-button-primary data-uk-dropdown = "{mode:'click'}"
        span Add Item

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that moving the mouse over the `div` allows the code to work. Therefore, I would try different ways of hovering over the element.

Try the `hover` method:

```
def create_item
  sleep(2)
  add_item_element.hover
  add_item_element.click
  sleep(2)
end
```

You could also try firing the respective events manually:

```
def create_item
  sleep(2)
  add_item_element.fire_event('onmouseover')
  add_item_element.click
  sleep(2)
end
```